# Can we approximate any open set by sub-domains with smooth boundary?

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, differential-topology, sobolev-spaces

In some books, mainly about PDEs, I read that any open set can be approximated by sub-domain with smooth boundary  (not just piecewise smooth). In 1 dimensional case, this seemly to be quite trivial: for any subdomain, use small open balls to cover its boundary and then mollify the connection parts. But in the higher dimensional case, I think this is not that obvious.

So the first question is:  how can we approximate any open set by sub-domain with smooth boundary?

And the second question is: In what meaning the approximation is? Pointwise, i.e., we can find subdomain $D_n$ with smooth boundary such that $D_n\uparrow A$? uniformly pointwise? Or in the Lebesgue measure sense? etc.

Comment: What would pointwise approximation of a set even mean?

Comment: @Anthony Carapetis We say a sequence $D_n\uparrow A$ if $\cup_{n\geq 1}D_n=A$. I make some misunderstanding here, I will correct this soon.

Comment: Oh, right, makes sense.

Comment: And what would $D_n\uparrow A$ "uniformly pointwise" mean?

Comment: @Michael Lee We define $A_n:=\{x\in A: \ d(x,\partial A)\geq \frac{1}{n}\}$. Then uniformly pointwise means that $\partial D_n\subset A\cap A_n^c$.

Comment: Yes, it's possible, using a Whitney decomposition of the open set. See, for example, the beginning of [Singular Integrals and Differentiability Properties of Functions](http://press.princeton.edu/titles/1976.html) by Stein.

Comment: @Michelle Can you show more details about this argument? I does not understand it quite clearly.

Comment: @Michelle I does not know how Whitney decomposition theorem is used here.

Comment: That's why you should read that book.

Answer (score 1):

The following proposition can be found in D. Daners, *Domain Perturbation for Linear and Semi-Linear Boundary Value Problems*, Handbook of differential equations, 2008.

> **Proposition 8.2.1.** Let $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be an open set. Then there exists a sequence of bounded open sets $\Omega_n$ with $C^\infty$-boundary such that $\Omega_n\Subset \Omega_{n+1}\Subset \Omega$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and $\Omega=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \Omega_n$. If $\Omega$ is connected, we can choose $\Omega_n$ to be connected as well.

The proof uses Sard's lemma.

Comment: Okay, this result is just what I want. Thanks for your kind reply!